# Angular 5 Firebase Auth Guard login status different to whats retuned from Auth Service

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, angular5, angularfire2

I'm pretty new to Angular and in the process of designing a small web app.

I created a simple email/password login using angularfire2. The authentication part works fine. However, it appears the authguard for some reason always thinks the user is logged out even though the `console.log` out from the auth service I created returns a user.

Here is my implementation:

**Service:**

```
export class AuthService {

  private user: Observable<firebase.User> = null;
  private userDetails: firebase.User = null;

  constructor(public firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {
    this.user = firebaseAuth.authState;
    this.user.subscribe(
      (user) => {
        if (user) {
          this.userDetails = user;
          console.log(this.userDetails.uid);
          console.log('service: logged');
        } else {
          this.userDetails = null;
          console.log('service: logged out');
        }
      }
    );
  }

isAuthenticated() {
     if (this.userDetails == null ) {
      return false;
     } else {
      return true;
     }
   }
}
```

i use **isAuthenticated()** function (in the AuthGuard) to establish whether the user is signed in or not.

**Auth Guard:**

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
              private router: Router) {}

  canActivate( route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

  if (this.authService.isAuthenticated()) {
      console.log('guard: user is logged in ')
      return true;
  } else {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      console.log('guard: user is not logged in ')
      return false;
  }
}
}
```

My question is, why does the function used in AuthGuard think the user is not logged in but the AuthService reckons the user is logged in? Also, i've noted when the page refreshes, user logs out. Is there any way to address both together?

Edit:

**Routes Array**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  { path: '', component: FullLayoutComponent, data: { title: 'home' }, children: HOME_ROUTES, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }, // 'home page' is here
  { path: '', component: ContentLayoutComponent, data: { title: 'content' }, children: CONTENT_ROUTES}, // login page is a child here

];
```

login page is defined as a child in CONTENT_ROUTES where the default route is HOME_ROUTES.

Comment: One to address the page refresh logout, you can use `localStorage` for the browser. Two, are you trying to invoke `CanActivate` on the same component that is setup in your routing as your `default route`? You may have to show your routes array

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply Andrew. I've updated the question with the routes array. To answer your question yes, auth guard is applied to the home page.

Comment: It looks as though you're default route for the app is route guard. Also `path` needs not to be blank. It can be like `path: 'home'` and `path: 'content'`. Make the Content routes the default since it has the login with the redirect.

Comment: Yes, the ‘home’ section has a side bar and a nav bar (and need to be logged in to access) and the content section is the login, register pages. All the separate routes are defined in a mother route array for HOME_ROUTES and CONTENT_ROUTES

Comment: @AndrewLobban re: logging out when browser refreshes, how can I rectify that please?

Comment: Store the `userDetails` when you get it from Firebase in localStorage using `localStorage.setItem()` and retrieve it in the `isAuthenticated()` using `localStorage.getItem()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170477/discussion-between-andrew-lobban-and-catzeye).